# Show spelling errors after changing language

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro in Word. This macro opens a document, changes the language for spelling purposes, saves and closes it.

The problem is when I reopen the document, the language is changed but the spelling errors aren't shown.

I tried some things and I've gotten to the conclusion that the "bug" is in the ActiveDocument.Save line. If I don't save the document, the errors are shown, but I need to save and close programmatically all the documents because this subroutine is part of another which manages a huge amount of documents and keeping open all of them or prompting the dialog box asking to save the document isn't a solution.

### The code

```
Sub MacroFoo()

     Documents.Open FileName:= _
        "C:\MyDir\foo.doc", _
        ConfirmConversions:=True, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
        WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:= _
        wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
    ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID = wdFrench
    ActiveDocument.Content.NoProofing = False
    ActiveDocument.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After a hard research in the Word object reference I found the solution.

With this line of code we force the count of errors:

```
ActiveDocument.SpellingErrors.Count
```

After saving and closing the document, we can check that the errors are displayed if we reopen it.

Thanks everybody. : )